# Determinant with general case at the diagnal

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I tried to calculate the determinant for that matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 1 & . &.&.& 1 \\ 
  1 & 1 & 1 & .  &.&.& 1 \\ 
  1 & 1 & 2 & . &. & .&1 \\
  .&.&. &. &&&1\\
  .& & & &.&& 1\\
  . & & & && .&1\\
  1 & 1& 1 &.& .& . & n-1  
\end{pmatrix}$

and im quit sure for n
\begin{align*}
 n \geq 2 
\end{align*}
it will be equal to
\begin{align*}
(n-1)!
\end{align*}

but i'm not sure and can't  understant how to prove that

Comment: please type in the matrix for your $n=2$ and for $n=3$  I can't see $(n-1)!$ as having anything to do with determinant of the matrix you have actually typed. Indeed, the determinant seems to be $-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determinant of your matrix $A$ is $-(n-2)!$
I apply row operations to $A$ that do not change the determinant.
(1) Subtract $R_1$ from all other rows.
(2) Subtract $R_2$ (new version!) from all later rows.
Ignoring zeros, you only have $\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}$
in the top left corner and an $(n-2) \times (n-2)$ diagonal matrix
$D$ at the bottom right. Thus, $|A|=(-1)|D|.$

Comment: I should have mentioned that fractional multiples of each of the last $n-2$ rows can be subtracted from the first row to give all its zeros. In fact, this omission has no effect on the determinant calculation I gave.

Comment: Ohh I really miss that.. Thank a lot!